# Cannot save modules with all pages menu assignment

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-manager

Okay so working in Joomla. I go to save a module but I cannot and instead get kicked back to the module page with a checkin on the module I just got kicked out of. With some testing it seems this issue only arises when on all pages is selected in menu assignment, anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Note this is is using 5.4 php and 3.7 Joomla

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

- set error reporting to maximum in Global Configuration
- check JavaScript Console for any meaningful errors
- try clearing Joomla and browser cache
- try an alternative browser
- run a backup and try reinstalling core files via Joomla Update component
- try changing the hosting to PHP 5.6 or PHP 7.0 if all your third party extensions support PHP 7.0
- try switching the the alternative administrator template in the back-end
- upgrade all third party extensions to the latest versions

Comment: Thanks man, Talked to our contractor turns out we just have too many modules on too many menues